# Get Azure OAuth2 token from flash application

Tags: flash, azure, oauth-2.0, xss

My flash application needs to access https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token, in order to get an OAuth2 token. However, I get a crossdomain error. Is there a way to add URLs to a crossdomain.xml file in Azure AD?

Comment: Sounds a bit like OAuth2 is used in a weird way. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: We're using Azure AD to secure a .Net WebApi2 project, which is going to be called by a legacy flash application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx describes the authorisation flow that we are using. This works perfectly when calling the api server to server eg from another .Net project, but we haven't been able to get around the xss issue from Flash.